# Adding first value together from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, sum

I am trying to add the first values together in a series of lists then add the second values together from a series of lists and so on.

for example:

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50]
b=[60,70,80,90,100]
c=[110,120,130,140,150]
```

So as a result I want:

```
[180, 210,240, 270, 300]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
total = 0
for I in range (0,a)
total = total +a[I]+b[I]+c[I]
return total
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you've shown here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1):

```
total = 0
for I in range (0,a):
    total = total +a[I]+b[I]+c[I]
return total
```

So, you have a few issues here with your code.

1. You can't use `range(0,a)`. `a` is list and not an integer. You would have to use the length of list, or `len(a)`.
2. You also aren't supposed to use capital letters as variables, unless they're constants variables, according to [PEP8 standards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants).
3. You're trying to return data that isn't inside a function. That won't work.
   You could do something like:

```
def add_vals_from_lists(a,b,c):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        total += sum([a[i], b[i], c[i]])
        # The above is a much cleaner way to write total = total +a[I]+b[I]+c[I]
    return total

a=[10,20,30,40,50]
b=[60,70,80,90,100]
c=[110,120,130,140,150]

add_vals_from_lists(a,b,c)
```

Or, you could merely `print(total)` instead of using `return total`.

But, this will simply add everything to total returning 1200, not what you want.

As Samwise and Pedro noted, you can simply write this in a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
`[sum(t) for t in zip(a, b, c)]`

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) - Iterate over several iterables in parallel, producing tuples with an item from each one. For each of these tuples, (10,60,110) for the first one, the list-comprehension will [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) each one. Resulting in a list of `[180, 210, 240, 270, 300]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum` and `zip` functions with a simple list comprehension:

```py
total = [sum(i) for i in zip(a,b,c)]
```

Or iterate over the indexes:

```py
total = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    total.append(a[i] + b[i] + c[i])
```

`total` has to be a `list` and you have to `append` to it on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to get the first element of each list, and then `sum` them:

```
>>> a=[10,20,30,40,50]
>>> b=[60,70,80,90,100]
>>> c=[110,120,130,140,150]
>>> [sum(t) for t in zip(a, b, c)]
[180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation needs to be corrected in your code. Also, collect the sum of the elements of a particular index in a list. If you simply add the elements, it'll add all the elements give you only the sum of all the things. Also, in the for loop statement, it should be len(a) and not only a. Your corrected code:

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50]
b=[60,70,80,90,100]
c=[110,120,130,140,150]
sums=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    sums.append(a[i]+b[i]+c[i])
print(sums)
```